# PURE C: Передать массив строк(массив символов) в функцию

Tags: c, массивы, строки, функции, 2d

Интересует возможность передачи массива массивов символов(строк) в функцию с возможностью, изменять значения этих строк глобально.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void get(char ***s) { //пробовал еще (char **s[2])
    *s[0] = "123";

    return;
}

int main() {
    char *s[] = { "abc", "def" };
    get(&s);
    printf("%s", s[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

По логике вещей все должно работать - если передаем просто число `a`, то `void get(int *a)`, массив символов `get(char **s)`, а вот с массивом строк уже не получается.
Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: Будьте проще --  `void get(char *s[]) {
    s[0] = "123";

    return;
}`, описывайте то, что реально создаете `int main() {
    char *s[] = { "abc", "def" };
    get(s);
    printf("%s", s[0]);
    return 0;
}`  (обратите внимание, заменил `&s` на `s` в вызове `get()`) и все будет работать (KISS-принцип)

Comment: Спасибо:)
Оказалось, что у меня это все тоже работало(нет): просто в дебаге показывало что ошибка чтения... а при запуске все корректно отрабатывало

Comment: Может и зависит от компилятора, но я думаю,  компилятор должен сказать, что тип параметра в объявлении функции `void get(char ***s)` не соответствует типу  аргумента в вызове `get(&s)` (для `char *s[]  = {...};`)

Answer (score 0):

Функция у вас требует указатель на указатель на указатель - вы написал лишний *. И в функцию тогда незачем передавать &s.